# Create XSD from XML with nested elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to create an XSD-file from an XML-file, but i get errors because there is a nested element with the same name as an upper element. The XML file looks (partly) like this:

```
- <comments>
  - <generalCommentData>
    <createDate>2016-03-18T07:36:48.272+0100</createDate> 
    <message>Test1</message> 
    ...
  - <replies>
    - <generalCommentData>
      <createDate>2016-03-18T07:36:48.272+0100</createDate> 
      <message>Test2</message> 
      ...
      <replies />
      </generalCommentData>
      ...
    </replies>
    </generalCommentData>
  </comments>
```

Basically this XML shows some comments which may contain some reply-comments (which can contain reply-comments again) but every comment is actually `generalCommentData`

What can i do to make things work? I'm not used to working with XML-Files and i have no idea what to do. I don't even know if i explained correctly...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an XSD that matches your XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="comments" type="CommentsType"/>
    <xsd:complexType name="CommentsType">
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="generalCommentData" type="CommentsDataType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>      
    <xsd:complexType name="CommentsDataType">
        <xsd:all>
            <xsd:element name="createDate" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
            <xsd:element name="message" type="xsd:string"/>
            <xsd:element name="replies" type="CommentsType"/>
        </xsd:all>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Things to notice:

- your XML seems to imply that an xsd:dateTime should work. Unfortunately, you're missing a colon, it should be `2016-03-18T07:36:48.272+01:00`; if indeed, that is the way the data is, then change the use of *xsd:dateTime* to an *xsd:string*
- You're looking for how to model a recursive structure using XSD. The above XSD shows one way of doing it, which in my opinion is the most compact for what you've shown with your sample. The key points are:

  - assuming that the content model of your root element is the same as the one of replies, then the global type **CommentsType** can be reused in both cases.
  - by reusing the **CommentsType** you achieve recursiveness.
  - your sample XML seems to imply that the **replies** element is mandatory.
  - As with most recursive concepts, there is an expectation that the algorithm/structure will eventually end. In my sample, this is achieved by virtue of making the **generalCommentData** optional. Without that, one would not be able to build a valid XML.

If you have different constraints, for e.g. your **comments** element must have at least one **generalCommentData** element, then your schema would have to be altered. The simplest way might be to just make sure the **replies** element is optional (which naturally makes sense). If **replies** must be mandatory, then the following approach will work instead:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!-- XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XSD Module (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <xsd:element name="comments">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="generalCommentData" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xsd:sequence>         
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>      
    <xsd:element name="generalCommentData">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:all>
                <xsd:element name="createDate" type="xsd:dateTime"/>
                <xsd:element name="message" type="xsd:string"/>
                <xsd:element name="replies">
                    <xsd:complexType>
                        <xsd:sequence>
                            <xsd:element ref="generalCommentData" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </xsd:sequence>         
                    </xsd:complexType>                  
                </xsd:element>
            </xsd:all>
        </xsd:complexType>      
    </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

This example shows you another way to implement a recursive structure, and that would be through an element reference, here **generalCommentData**.

There is a third way, using group references; if you really need that, I'll leave it up to you to find it; just search for recursive XML Schemas.

On a final note, I've used *xsd:all* as the compositor. If you require order, or elements that should be repeating, then switch to an *xsd:sequence* instead.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer :) the dateTime actually is a String and its not mandatory that each comment has at least one reply, thats correct. By now i found a workaround for my problem. I just opened the XML File in Visual Studio and clicked XML > Create Schema. That worked just beautiful for me. Before, i wanted to use the Command-Line-Tool from VIsual studio to create a XSD-File from the XML which didn't work properly, but now everything is fine.